# Plugin keeps saying needs to be updated and it's in a constant loop

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I have a plugin that is on "Version 1.0"

When I update it (as indicated within my dashboard) it revers back to the same message.

The plugin is at "1.0" and the "update" is also at "1.0" so clearly there's an error or mismatch.

Question is: how do I remove the loop?

Thanks!

Comment: You should contact the plugin author. But sounds like a caching issue.

Comment: If it's actually *your* plugin, please show the relevant code and we might be able to help.

Comment: Have you named your plugin something that's already in use on the .org plugin repo?

Comment: @henry what's the name of the plugin? And is this a bespoke plugin you wrote? Or one you downloaded? If so where from?

Comment: @SallyCJ I did but not much joy, he just said ignore it. Tom J Nowell - no, and I downloaded from developers own site - it's legit - just slopply coded that's all...i was wondering if there's a way to "fix it" as updated?

Comment: @henry I believe there is, if we can see the code.

Comment: But if the author says ignore it, then maybe just ignore it.. Or you can try changing/checking the `Version` line/header in main file of the (updated) plugin.

Comment: HTF is this off-topic? Seriously - there are a bunch of very bored people that just go around down voting and generally acting so negative to genuine people with genuine questions....honestly......smh......

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'd just deactivate then uninstall then install again. Depending on the plugin, you might lose some customization or settings. But a lot of plugins don't remove anything they stored in the wp-options table (normally where plugin options are stored), so you may not lose any settings.

But I'd go to the plugins' support page. That's the best place for plugin support.

**Added**

Since the plugin support route didn't work, perhaps you can 'force' the plugin not to be checked for updates.

This question has some ways to do it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17897044/wordpress-how-to-disable-plugin-update

with this code (adjust for the plugin's folder):

```
add_filter('site_transient_update_plugins', 'remove_update_notification');
function remove_update_notification($value) {
     unset($value->response[ plugin_basename(__FILE__) ]);
     return $value;
}
```

Put that in the site's function.php (optimally in a Child Theme), or in a (possibly private) plugin of your own.

Comment: Thanks, I did that but no joy. I just get the feeling its a sloppy bit of coding. The plugin works great but there's just this nagging issue about the updating...

Comment: Any other ideas anyone?

Comment: @henry there are some important questions in the comments on the main question you didn't answer with people waiting

Comment: ^ noted - I didn't see previous replies

Comment: @henry - for another approach, see my modified answer.